# Is it possible to change the device name programatically in Attachmate EXTRA?

Tags: c#, extra, attachmate-extra

I've written a win forms application that uses Attachmate EXTRA.  The application itself works great but I was just notified that there is a need to be able to switch to different device names for the sessions.  The names would be set before the sessions are launched and then the session would go through the connection process.  The only way I can think to do this is create and save a separate session with each device name needed and go that route but I would like to be able to do this dynamically instead if possible.

I've tried doing this during debug to look at the object but have been unable to find a method or property to set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having a support ticket entered and getting confirmation, the only way to change the device name programatically is to open the .EDP file, replace the string with the new device name, save the file and then run that .EDP file.

Apparently their new application, Reflection, can handle these types of things with calls without making changes to the files.